# How to download a complete forum-site with wget or otherwise

Tags: wget

Im aware this is an old question and I have tried a few options but without sucess. If Ihad time I could probably figure it out, but Im in a hurry since the forum is closing down soon. 
Question: Im trying to download a forum
It needs my username and password.

I have tried httrack to no avail so I want to give wget a shoot.
Please help if you can as Im in a hurry and there is so much information there that will vanish if no one downloads it.

I have tried this `wget` command

```
wget \ > --recursive \ > --no-clobber \ > --page-requisites \ > --html-extension \ > --convert-links \ > --restrict-file-names=windows \ > --domains website.org \ > --no-parent \ > wald-electronics.freeforums.net
```

This did download SOME posts, but really not all.
And I have also tried alot of different commands, but all to no avail.

Comment: have you tried archive.org?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget) which details using cookies with `wget`. That said, the forum login page at  `wald-electronics.freeforums.net` potentially uses some JavaScript in its login, so that might present issues.

Comment: Thanks, will try as fast as I can

Answer (score 0):

To begin with: `--domains website.org` does not belong here. Remove this. Or put the right domain name (NB: this might include subdomains if any).

Next, be aware that many websites block the **bots**. So you might want to change the **user agent** to masquerade a real browser, although this could work with no problem. Try to be gentle and add some pauses between the page downloads. A server can detect non-human activity - ie browsing at high speed without pause - and respond by blocking or throttling.

This site may also require a **login** so that you can properly index the contents. You need to figure out how to pass the credentials to `wget` or reuse a token from our browser cookies maybe.

You are on the right track but reading the [wget manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) could be beneficial so that you have an overview of the options available to fine-tune your command.

If you are having too much trouble, maybe there is a browser plugin that exists for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you and I will remove it .